# Lebesgue measurable but not Riemann integrable

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Every bounded function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$, which is Riemann integrable, it is also Lebesgue integrable.

On the other hand 
$$
g(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
1 & \text{if} & x\in\mathbb Q\cap[0,1], \\
0 & \text{if} & x\in [0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q,
\end{array}
\right. \tag{1}
$$
i.e., $g=\chi_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q}$, is Lebesgue integrable in $[0,1]$, but not Riemann integrable.

In fact, a bounded function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable if and only if it is almost everywhere continuous.

Now, the function $g=\chi_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q}$ is not Riemann integrable BUT is it  almost everywhere equal to $h\equiv 0$, which IS Riemann integrable.

My question is the following:

*Is there a bounded function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$, which is Lebesgue integrable, and it is not equal almost everywhere to a Riemann integrable function*?

Comment: Is $$
g(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
1 & \text{if} & x\in\mathbb Q\cap[0,1], \\
0 & \text{if} & x\in [0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q,
\end{array}
\right. \tag{1}
$$ Lebesgue measurable function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The characteristic function of a "fat Cantor set" (a Cantor set with positive measure), is Lebesgue integrable, but is not equal almost everywhere to a Riemann integrable function, because every point of the fat Cantor set is a discontinuity of its characteristic function.

Comment: Is $$
g(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
1 & \text{if} & x\in\mathbb Q\cap[0,1], \\
0 & \text{if} & x\in [0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q,
\end{array}
\right. \tag{1}
$$ Lebesgue measurable function?

Comment: Yes, because it is equal almost everywhere to the zero function; its Lebesgue integral equals zero. It is also equal almost everywhere to a Riemann integrable function (the zero function).